# Where is the conda config file located? (anaconda.conf)

Tags: conda

I was looking into the different options in the conda config file. At some point I did `conda config --set verbosity 4` (even though it goes to 3, and since then if no matter what I do, it'll give me this error if I try to do something with conda. I have tried to change the verbosity level down to 0,1,2 and 3, which are the possible options, but to no avail.

I can't delete the enviroments anymore due to this, which was the only idea I had left, thinking it might be the enviroment variable.

edit: So if I can get to the config file then I can change it by editing it directly (I hope), but to find the location you would usually do the `conda info` command, but I can't use that due to the error underneath. If anyone can tell me in semi detail from the user// location where its located then I can change it (hopefully).

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/beerh/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/gateways/logging.py", line 232, in set_verbosity
        set_all_logger_level(VERBOSITY_LEVELS[verbosity_level])
    IndexError: tuple index out of range
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/beerh/anaconda3/bin/conda-env", line 7, in <module>
        sys.exit(main())
      File "/home/beerh/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda_env/cli/main.py", line 90, in main
        init_loggers(context)
      File "/home/beerh/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 65, in init_loggers
        set_verbosity(context.verbosity)
      File "/home/beerh/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/gateways/logging.py", line 234, in set_verbosity
        raise CondaError("Invalid verbosity level: %(verbosity_level)s",
    conda.CondaError: Invalid verbosity level: 4
```

Comment: https://www.anaconda.com/blog/conda-configuration-engine-power-users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file that you need to go to is the `.condarc` file, which is located in `\\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\user`. It's one of the files there, just open it with Notepad++ (or any other editor) and change the verbosity.